# How can I retrieve the height of a div in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xhtml

I am absolutly new in JavaScript and JQuery.

I have a JQuery script that is performed each time the user click on a node of a **JSTree**:

```
$("#treeId2").bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {

    // DO SOMETHING

})
```

In this script I have to retrieve the height of the div having **id=treeId2**

How can I do this thing in JQuery?

Tnx

Comment: Um, by using `.height()`?

Answer (score 3):

```
var heightInPixels = $('#treeld2').height();
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this!

```
$("#treeId2").height();
```

Or, in line with your question:

```
$("#treeId2").bind("select_node.jstree", function (event, data) {

    alert($("#treeId2").height());

});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in some ways, for example:

```
$('#element').height()           
$('#element').innerHeight()              
$('#element').outerHeight()              
$('#element').outerHeight(true)
```

Above functions count height element with various combination including
 - padding
 - border
 - margin
 - extact height of element

[image]
See diferences of each usage [here](http://www.texelate.co.uk/blog/post/91-jquery-whats-the-difference-between-height-innerheight-and-outerheight/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
$('#treeId2').on('click', function(){
 var height = $(this).height();
 //other code`
})
```

Reference (jquery docs are great): http://api.jquery.com/height/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.height()` to find an element height, but you should not be using [**.bind()**](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), its deprecated post jQuery 1.7. You can use `.click()`:

```
$("#treeId2").click(function () {
   var height = $(this).height();
});
```

or you can use `.on()`:

```
$("#treeId2").on("click", function () {
   var height = $(this).height();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery has the .height() method, so using something like:

```
$("#treeId2").height()
```

should return what you are looking for.

It is worth noting that this does not take padding, margins, or borders into account.

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/height/)

Comment: `.outerheight()` can be used to take borders, padding etc into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#treeId2").on("click", function () {
  var height = $(this).height();
});
```